# Services to find very large project?

Tags: attracting-clients

Is it realistic to think that there are services where you can find large projects of over $500k? They are of course for teams of 10+, not for individuals or small teams.

So far, all projects I saw on freelancing sites or via personal connections were of max $100k.

My question is, are such large project offered to the remote teams or they are reserved strictly for companies that have local office in that country (so they better deal with legal issues in trouble time)?

The root of this question is that I have never seen such projects offered online to remote teams. So I would like to know they rules and chances to bid to such large projects.

If this seem off topic, it is not. So please ask me to elaborate more my question if it's unclear.

Comment: Would you spend 500k on a team that lives on the other side of the world, that you have never seen IRL? I know I wouldn't, and I can't imagine any of my clients doing that either, including (or especially) the type of clients that have 500k projects to begin with.

Comment: @user3244085 Why being remote is an obstacle to meet? I meet each of my client via video conferencing and a few of them actually visited me. Also quality portfolio will make them think of me twice.

Comment: Companies with million-dollar (or half-million) projects to complete aren't out shopping for agencies. Unlike smaller projects, these types of clients are a commodity and agencies actively market companies for them. There's no need for a service you describe. Agencies market **to the client** and the company chooses between the advertising materials they receive. This is why agencies capable of completing million-dollar projects have a sales team.

Comment: @Scott But the have to post their "need" somewhere? How else would other companies know that XY company has a need for some service?

Comment: Why do they "have to post a need"? Doesn't *every* business need IT/Dev services? I mean *every* business. The larger the company the more imperative the need. Chances of you finding a $500k+ company *without* the need are slim. So one can assume, you can cold advertise to these companies - which is what agencies do. Large companies don't need to go "looking" anywhere for services. They get offers then they vet the offers. Much the same way *every* human needs bathroom tissue. You don't go asking companies to sell you... the companies advertise to you directly to sway you to their brand.

Comment: @Scott You may actually be right. Thanks scott

Answer (score 1):

Some governments have tender websites where departments request tenders ([RFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_tender)) for a product or service to be delivered. Government tenders often have particular requirements such as the use of local employees or a pre-qualification process before being able to tender.

Outside of government, the process is often referred to as a request for proposal ([RFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_proposal)) but there isn't necessarily a central point of contact for these and companies may send an RFP to a short list of service providers who they know may be able to provide the required product or service.

**Update:** Searching the web for "tenders" does show some websites that aim to put service seekers in touch with service providers and these websites may be what you are looking for.